# Check | Drop | Create | Insert Table with PHP for ODBC

Tags: php, sql, odbc

I am really struggling with this...

I get this thing to work about 90% of the way... What I am having trouble with, is verifying if the table exists yet or not...

I have 2 like pages, the first just sends a `$_POST` to the main functions page. It's a single input.

Scenario: One input is submitted to submit.php and inserted into temp db, then while on this page, more inputs can be inserted until completed... We'll stop there.

What it needs to do, check to make sure the table DOESN'T EXIST from the beginning, Drop it if it does. Create the table - then insert and update Row count.

Here is what I have so far:

```
#17 - $FirstSub = $_SESSION['version'];  //True if this is the first time page has loaded

   if(isset($conn)){    // Check connection
//create table string
$createTemp = "CREATE TABLE temp_Ticket_Tracker(
PickT_Num int NOT NULL UNIQUE,
us_name varchar(20) NOT NULL,
ticket_status varchar(10) NOT NULL,
time_stamp varchar(20) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY(PickT_Num)
)"; 
  //Insert String
$insert = "INSERT INTO temp_Ticket_Tracker VALUES ('". $_POST['PickNum'] ."','{$_SESSION['User']}','GREEN','{$TimeStamp}')";
//row count string
$query = "Select COUNT(*) as TicketNum FROM temp_Ticket_Tracker";
//Duplicate tester string
$tested = "SELECT PickT_Num FROM temp_Ticket_Tracker WHERE '". $_POST['PickNum'] ."' = PickT_Num";
 //Drop's table 
$drop = "DROP TABLE temp_Ticket_Tracker";


//Here is where it starts to screw up -
#35 - $firstTest = odbc_exec($conn,$query); //execution string
$NumRows = odbc_fetch_array($firstTest); //Sets array
$countingRows = $NumRows['TicketNum'];  


//This is "Supposed" to ask is this the first time you've been here and does the table exist? Answer (Yes, Yes)

if($FirstSub === 'true' && $countingRows >= 1){ 
    odbc_exec($conn,$drop);
    odbc_exec($conn,$createTemp);
    odbc_exec($conn,$insert);        
    $_SESSION['version'] = 'false'; 
    $int = odbc_exec($conn,$query);
    $intNum = odbc_fetch_array($int);
    $TicCount = $intNum['TicketNum'];
    odbc_close($conn);

  //Again asks if first time and does the table exist? Answer should be(Yes, NO)
}else if($FirstSub === 'true' && !$firstTest){
    odbc_exec($conn,$createTemp);
    odbc_exec($conn,$insert);        
    $_SESSION['version'] = 'false'; 
    $int = odbc_exec($conn,$query);
    $intNum = odbc_fetch_array($int);
    $TicCount = $intNum['TicketNum'];
    odbc_close($conn);


    //Asks if this is first time and assums Table is created
}else if($FirstSub === 'false'){
        $is = odbc_exec($conn,$tested);
        $test = odbc_fetch_array($is);

    //Check to make sure duplicate has not been entered
    if($test == NULL){
        odbc_exec($conn,$insert);
        $int = odbc_exec($conn,$query);
        $intNum = odbc_fetch_array($int);
        $TicCount = $intNum['TicketNum'];
        odbc_close($conn);

        //Passes error if duplicate is used
    }else{
        echo '<script type="text/javascript">',
        'window.onload = function() {',
        'document.getElementById("error").innerHTML = "You have already scanned this ticket!";};',
        '</script>';
        $int = odbc_exec($conn,$query);
        $intNum = odbc_fetch_array($int);
        $TicCount = $intNum['TicketNum'];

    }

}else{
    echo '<p> OOPS! looks like we may have a problem!</p>';
    $_SESSION['version']='true';
}
  }else{echo "Try again...";}
```

Everything works perfectly! Except when the entire table is submitted (off screen) and the temp table is dropped...

input is coming in as `[FirstSub = "true" & table does NOT Exist]`

I get this error...

> Warning: odbc_exec() [function.odbc-exec]: SQL error: [Microsoft][ODBC
>   SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Invalid object name
>   'temp_Ticket_Tracker'., SQL state S0002 in SQLExecDirect in C:\Program
>   Files (x86)\EasyPHP5.3.0\www\idea\ticket\greenFunction.php on line 35
>
> Warning: odbc_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource,
>   boolean given in C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\EasyPHP5.3.0\www\idea\ticket\greenFunction.php on line 36 (Line
>   numbers look like #n - )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are looking for this SQL command:

```
IF OBJECT_ID ('YourDatabase.YourSchema.temp_Ticket_Tracker') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE Temp_Ticket_Tracker
```

This will check if the table exists then drop it if it does.  Replace `$drop` with it, and you can take out some of your other table check logic.

```
$drop = "IF OBJECT_ID ('YourDatabase.YourSchema.temp_Ticket_Tracker') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE Temp_Ticket_Tracker";
```